# React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function but got: undefined

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-router, react-router-dom

I have a parent Component as **app.js**

```
import React, { Component } from 'react'
import { Route, Link, BrowserRouter, HashRouter} from 'react-router-dom'
//import BrowserHistory from 'react-router/lib/BrowserHistory'
import {Scholarships} from './scholarships'

class App extends Component {
        render() {
                return (
                        <div>
                        <HashRouter>
                            <div>
                                <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
                                <Route path='/hello' component={Hello} />
                                <Route path='/scholarship' component={Scholarships} />

                            </div>
                        <Scholarships /> 
                        </HashRouter>
                        </div>

                )

        }
}

const Home = () => <h1> Hello from home! </h1>
const Hello = () => <h2> Hello React </h2>

export default App
```

and there is a child component as **scholarships.js**

```
import React, {Component} from 'react'
import Request from 'react-http-request' //`https://www.npmjs.com/package/react-http-request`

class Scholarships extends Component {
        constructor(props) {
                super(props);
        }
        render() {
                return (
                        <Request
                                url = 'https://api.github.com/users/mbasso'
                                method = 'get'
                                accept = 'application/json'
                                verbose = {true}
                        >
                                {
                                        ({error, result, loading}) => {
                                                        if(loading) {
                                                                return <div id="scholarships"> loading... </div>;
                                                        }
                                                        else {
                                                                return <div id="scholarships"> { JSON.stringify(result) }</div> ;
                                                        }

                                                }
                                }
                        </Request>
                )
        }
}

export default Scholarships
```

It is throwing an error **Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `App`.  bundle.js:357:9** and
**Error: A  may have only one child element** 
I'm just starting with react so it might be a noob question but I am struck up here, If I pass `<Scholarships />` directly into **main.js** it is working as expected why I am not able to nest it here

Additionally I've also tried

- `const scholarship = () => <Scholarships />`
- `const scholarship = <Scholarships />`
- `const scholarship = () => (<Scholarships />)`
- `const scholarship = () => {Scholarships}`

I would also like to know that my **Scholarship** component is return plain JSON.Stringify text so why is it still a Object in reference of the error given by `const scholarship = () => <Scholarship />`

My **main.js** file

```
import React from 'react'
import ReactDOM from 'react-dom'
import App from './app'
import Scholarships from './scholarships'
ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById('root'))
```

Comment: The problem is within your App component's `render()`.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly can you elaborate ?

Comment: Look at the answer of the duplicate: http://stackoverflow.com/a/33385872/1317805.

Comment: @JamesDonnelly I have edited the question and error thrown by console, I've already tried that way too, I just don't work and giving different error.

Answer (score -1):

Write it like this:

```
<HashRouter>
    <div>
        <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
        <Route path='/hello' component={Hello} />
        <Route path='/scholarship' component={Scholarship} />
    </div>
    <Scholarships />
</HashRouter>
```

**Reason**: A React component can't return multiple `React` elements, but a single `JSX` expression can have multiple children, so if you want a component to render multiple things you can wrap them in a `div`.

Don't forget that the `render()` function is exactly a function. Functions always take in a number of parameters and always return exactly one value.

**Update**:

Render the routes like this, it will work:

```
ReactDOM.render(
    <HashRouter>
        <div>
            <Route exact path='/' component={Home} />
            <Route path='/hello' component={Hello} />
            <Route path='/scholarship' component={Scholarships} />

        </div>
        <Scholarships /> 
    </HashRouter>,
    document.getElementbyId('root')
)
```

Comment: check the updated answer for reason.

Comment: `Warning: React.createElement: type is invalid -- expected a string (for built-in components) or a class/function (for composite components) but got: undefined. You likely forgot to export your component from the file it's defined in. Check the render method of `App`.  bundle.js:357:9`

`Error: A <Router> may have only one child element`

Throws this after the change

Comment: r u rendering `App` in `ReactDOM.render(...)` ??

Comment: Check the updated question, pasted the **main.js** as well

Comment: check the updated answer, render the routes directly inside ReactDOM.render, it will work. Reason i don't know i searched alot but didn't find the reason of this.  I tried many ways but this is the only way it was working :) i voted to reopen ur question may be someone provide the reason of that.

Comment: Its good to test it, But I am looking to convert the entire frontend into react and going with this approach will make a hell lot of mess in the main.js and management of that.