# I want to use two tr in render() { return

Tags: reactjs

I want to use two tr tags in a return as below:

```
render() {
  return<tr>row1</tr><tr>row2</tr>
}
```

and it gives me error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.

I know that we need to wrap these in a common component. But if I wrap there in a div tag for example:

```
return <div><tr>row1</tr><tr>row2</tr></div>
```

then my layout changes.

Is there any way to achieve the required.

Comment: did you forget close the bracket it the real code?

Comment: you need to change the structure then, wrap them in `td`.

Comment: You can return an array if you are using React v16.

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284169/parse-error-adjacent-jsx-elements-must-be-wrapped-in-an-enclosing-tag)

Answer (score 1):

If you really want to render two rows without parent wrapping them (like a `td`, `table` or so), I suggest you to create a second component which "wraps" its children accordingly. However, this works only from React16 onwards.

```
const Main = props => {
 return props.children
}
```

in your `render` method:

```
render() {
  return (
    <Main> 
      <tr>Row 1</tr>
      <tr>Row 2</tr>
    </Main>
  )
}
```

There's also a npm package which handles that if you want: https://github.com/gajus/react-aux

Comment: I seriously doubt this works. The `Main` component is still a React component and in your code example you are returning `children`, which is an array with two React Components. Arrays are not a valid React element (unless React v16 which is still in RC). That said, if I'm missing something and you can demo this with a working example I'll happily change my downvote into an upvote.

Comment: You are correct to say that `Main` is a react compoent. However it's not a DOM element (which is what you want to achieve).  You can also check `react-aux` repo and read its docs. It says exactly what I just answered :)

Comment: Well, here's my test: https://jsfiddle.net/f4x8knuy/ and if you look at the console it complains about invalid React element being returned.

Comment: @Chris You are correct. This is a mistake. It works for React 16 only :)