# How to render Drawer Navigation and Tab Navigation at the same time?

Tags: android, reactjs, react-native

I am trying to find a way to use Drawer Navigation and Tab Navigation in React Native. When I tried to put the components together, I get this error:

> Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.

Here is what I got so far:

```
 /* Imports */
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import {AppRegistry, Text, View, StyleSheet, TouchableHighlight, TouchableOpacity, YellowBox} from 'react-native';
import { StackNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { DrawerNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import { TabNavigator } from 'react-navigation';
import BottomNavigation, { Tab } from 'react-native-material-bottom-navigation';
import { NavigationComponent } from 'react-native-material-bottom-navigation';
import Icon from 'react-native-vector-icons/MaterialIcons';
import PropTypes from 'prop-types';

import HomeScreen from './Screens/HomeScreen';
import LoginScreen from './Screens/LoginScreen';
import RegisterScreen from './Screens/RegisterScreen';
import ProfileScreen from './Screens/ProfileScreen';
import UserListScreen from './Screens/UserListScreen';
import OtherUserScreen from './Screens/OtherUserScreen';
import OtherTagsScreen from './Screens/OtherTagsScreen';
import QuoteMachineScreen from './Screens/QuoteMachineScreen';
import SideBar from './Screens/SideBar';

/* Main */
class Home extends Component {
  constructor(props) {

   super(props);

   YellowBox.ignoreWarnings([
    'Warning: componentWillMount is deprecated',
    'Warning: componentWillReceiveProps is deprecated',
  ]);

 }




}




export default class myapp extends Component{

    render(){
      return(
        /* Main View  */

        /* End Main View */

      <AppDrawerNavigator />
      <TabNav />

      );
    }
}
/*End Main */

/*Navs*/

 const TabNav = TabNavigator({
  HomeScreen: { screen: HomeScreen },
  LoginScreen: { screen: LoginScreen },
  RegisterScreen: { screen: RegisterScreen },
}, {
  tabBarComponent: NavigationComponent,
  tabBarPosition: 'bottom',
  tabBarOptions: {
    bottomNavigationOptions: {
      labelColor: '#333',
      rippleColor: 'white',
      tabs: {
        HomeScreen: {
          barBackgroundColor: '#EEEEEE',
          activeLabelColor: '#212121',
        },
        LoginScreen: {
          barBackgroundColor: '#00796B'
        },
        RegisterScreen: {
          barBackgroundColor: '#EEEEEE', // like in the standalone version, this will override the already specified `labelColor` for this tab
          activeLabelColor: '#212121',
          activeIcon: <Icon size={24} color="#212121" name="newsstand" />
        }
      }
    }
  }
});

const AppDrawerNavigator = DrawerNavigator({
  LoginScreen: {screen: LoginScreen},
  RegisterScreen: {screen: RegisterScreen},
  ProfileScreen: {screen: ProfileScreen},
  UserListScreen: {screen:UserListScreen},
  HomeScreen: {screen: HomeScreen},
  OtherUserScreen: {screen: OtherUserScreen},
  OtherTagsScreen: {screen: OtherTagsScreen},
  QuoteMachineScreen: {screen: QuoteMachineScreen},
},
{
    initialRouteName: "HomeScreen",
    contentOptions: {
      activeTintColor: "#e91e63"
    },
    contentComponent: props => <SideBar {...props} />
  },

);

const AppStackNav = StackNavigator ({
  LoginScreen: {screen: LoginScreen},
  RegisterScreen: {screen: RegisterScreen},
  ProfileScreen: {screen: ProfileScreen},
  UserListScreen: {screen:UserListScreen},
  HomeScreen: {screen: HomeScreen},
  OtherUserScreen: {screen: OtherUserScreen},
  OtherTagsScreen: {screen: OtherTagsScreen},
})

/* Styles */
const styles = StyleSheet.create({
    headerText: {
    textAlign: 'center',
    fontSize: 30,
  },
    flexStyle: {
      flex: 1,
    },
    container: {
      flexDirection: 'row',
      height: 50,
    },
    v1: {
      flex: 1,
      padding: 10,
      backgroundColor: '#333',
      alignItems:'center'
    },
    v2: {
      flex: 1,
      padding: 10,
      backgroundColor: 'gold',
      alignItems:'center',
      justifyContent: 'center'
    },
    v3: {
      flex: 1,
      padding: 10,
      backgroundColor: 'gold',
      alignItems:'center'
    }
});

/* Registry */
AppRegistry.registerComponent('myapp', () => myapp);
```

Another thing I tried doing is just put them in a separate screen. For example, I would put Drawer Navigation component in the App.JS and then Tab Navigation component in the HomeScreen.JS, but that caused the whole app to go white. Then I went to the debugger and found that it was a Delta Bundler problem. I just can't seem to figure this problem out.

Answer (score 0):

You may be digging too deep for this problem.  The error reads, "Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.".  Double check the render method of your `myapp` class.  You need to return a *single* component, so you should wrap the two components in a container.

Duplicate issue - [Parse Error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284169/parse-error-adjacent-jsx-elements-must-be-wrapped-in-an-enclosing-tag)

Comment: Okay, so I wrapped `AppDrawerNavigator` and `TabNav` in `View` and now my screen is white.