# Redirect href from specific mobile devices

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I found code on here some while ago. I'm trying to have my href link redirect based on the device viewing the page. This is what I originally found:

```
$(document).ready(function($){
    var deviceAgent = navigator.userAgent.toLowerCase();
    var agentID = deviceAgent.match(/(iphone|ipod|ipad)/);
    if (agentID) {
        $('#myLink').attr('href', 'http://example.com/useiOSapp.html');
    }else
     { $('#myLink').attr('href', 'http://example.com/flash-app-page.html');  }
});
```

But on this code, I'm getting the following error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag (3:0)

Any ideas?

Comment: Where are your JSX elements? I suspect you are looking at the wrong file. See https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284169/parse-error-adjacent-jsx-elements-must-be-wrapped-in-an-enclosing-tag I think the error you're getting is unrelated to your main question.

Comment: Yes so it says a syntax error in my console. Not sure where it is though

Comment: It should tell you the file name - the file where the error is occurring.

Comment: Would you mind looking at a codepen?

https://codepen.io/marcelduplessis/pen/Gzdryz

Comment: Thanks so much Andy!

Answer (score 1):

This is a JSX error, and should be unrelated to your redirect if/else.

Answer (score 0):

From your codepen (codepen.io/marcelduplessis/pen/Gzdryz), you're confusing a javascript file with a html file. You don't need to put your javascript inside `<script>` tags in a javascript file - you would do that in a html file. I'd suggest going back to basics on javascript.