# eslint error about .jsx flie tag in vue-project when I npm run dev

Tags: javascript, vue.js, jsx, eslint

**Note:** this question is tagged with `vue` and shouldn't considered a duplicate of [Parse Error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284169/parse-error-adjacent-jsx-elements-must-be-wrapped-in-an-enclosing-tag), which instead refers to react.

---

I have a question about vue project about eslint and jsx.

My repository:

[https://github.com/1Crazy/TodoList-Vue/tree/eslintAboutJSX，](https://github.com/1Crazy/TodoList-Vue/tree/eslintAboutJSX%EF%BC%8C)

My `app.vue` file

```
<template>
  <div id="app">
    <div id="cover">
      <Header></Header>
      <Todo></Todo>
      <Footer></Footer>
    </div>
  </div>
</template>

<script>
import Header from './layout/header.vue'
import Footer from './layout/footer.jsx'
import Todo from './views/todo/todo.vue'

export default {
  components: {
    Header,
    Todo,
    Footer,
  }
}
</script>
```

when I `run npm run dev` I get

> Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag.

```
F:\project\vueprctice\client\app.vue
  11:1  error  Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?

   9 | </template>
  10 |
> 11 | <script>
     | ^
  12 | import Header from './layout/header.vue'
  13 | import Footer from './layout/footer.jsx'
  14 | import Todo from './views/todo/todo.vue'

F:\project\vueprctice\client\layout\header.vue
  7:1  error  Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?

   5 | </template>
   6 |
>  7 | <script>
     | ^
   8 | export default {
   9 |
  10 | }

F:\project\vueprctice\client\views\todo\item.vue
  2:14  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token

  1 | <template>
> 2 |   <div :class= "['todo-item',todo.completed ? 'completed' : '']">
    |              ^
  3 |     <input
  4 |       type="checkbox"
  5 |       class="toggle"

F:\project\vueprctice\client\views\todo\tabs.vue
  8:9  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token

   6 |         v-for="state in states"
   7 |         v-bind:key="state"
>  8 |         :class="[state,filter === state ? 'actived' : '']"
     |         ^
   9 |         @click="toggleFilter(state)"
  10 |       >
  11 |         {{showText(state)}}

F:\project\vueprctice\client\views\todo\todo.vue
  8:7  error  Parsing error: Unexpected token

   6 |       autofocus="autofocus"
   7 |       placeholder="接下来要做什么？"
>  8 |       @keyup.enter="addTodo"
     |       ^
   9 |     >
  10 |     <Item
  11 |       :todo="todo"
```

I hope to run `npm run dev` with no eslint errors, any help?

Comment: Check out this: https://vuejs.github.io/eslint-plugin-vue/user-guide/#what-is-the-use-the-latest-vue-eslint-parser-error

Comment: I try again，error still exists

Comment: thansk,I tried to read this article https://vuejs.github.io/eslint-plugin-vue/user-guide/#faq ，My problem is solved !