# React to add slide pane having some trouble

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native

Im beginner for *Reactjs**, im tried to add this [slide pane](https://www.w3schools.com/howto/tryit.asp?filename=tryhow_js_collapse_sidepanel) for my react project. added slide pane is not working correctly, anyone know how to add this correctly for the reactjs.

**[Stack blitz Here](https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ozq4vr)**
Thanks

**My code part**

**AgentView.js**

```
    import React, { Component } from 'react';
    import {
      Button,
      Card,
      CardBody,
      CardGroup,
      Col, Container,
      Form,
      Input,
      InputGroup,
      InputGroupAddon,
      InputGroupText,
      Row
    } from "reactstrap";

    import './AgentView.css';
    class AgentView extends Component {
      render() {
        return (
          <Container>
            <div id="mySidepanel" class="sidepanel">
  <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
  <a href="#">About</a>
  <a href="#">Services</a>
  <a href="#">Clients</a>
  <a href="#">Contact</a>
</div>

<button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Toggle Sidepanel</button>

          </Container>


        );  }

    }





    export default AgentView;
```

**AgentView.test.js**

```
 import React from 'react';
    import ReactDOM from 'react-dom';
    import { MemoryRouter } from 'react-router-dom';
    import AgentView from './AgentView';

    it('renders without crashing', () => {
      const div = document.createElement('div');
      ReactDOM.render(<MemoryRouter><AgentView/></MemoryRouter>, div);
      ReactDOM.unmountComponentAtNode(div);




     function openNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "250px";
}

function closeNav() {
  document.getElementById("mySidepanel").style.width = "0";
}
      })();
    });
```

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284169/parse-error-adjacent-jsx-elements-must-be-wrapped-in-an-enclosing-tag)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Read the error

`"JSX expressions must have one parent element."`

Googling this error will quickly give you the answer.

React is built with JSX and one of the rules is that each expression must be wrapped in a parent. Your sidePanel div and button were siblings without a parent. So wrapping them in a div fixes the issue and the component will render.

https://stackblitz.com/edit/react-ni1uvx

```js
render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <div id="mySidepanel" class="sidepanel">
          <a href="javascript:void(0)" class="closebtn" onclick="closeNav()">×</a>
          <a href="#">About</a>
          <a href="#">Services</a>
          <a href="#">Clients</a>
          <a href="#">Contact</a>
        </div>
        <button class="openbtn" onclick="openNav()">☰ Toggle Sidepanel</button>
      </div>
    );
  }
```

Comment: Sir, Thanks for your guidance , but why not working button and panel

Comment: @core114 looks like your openNav/closeNav functions need to be fixed. onClick you should setState and based on state show/hide nav. i.e. this.state.openNav === true