# Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag with bootstrap columns

Tags: reactjs, react-bootstrap

I am using React Bootstrap and trying to loop through content which is in two separate columns like this:

```
  <Container>
    <Row>
      {this.state.products.map(product => (
      <Col md={8}>
        <div className="title">{product.name}</div>
        <div className="desc">{product.description}</div>
      </Col>
      <Col md={4}>
        <div className="price">{product.price}</div>
      </Col>
      ))}
    </Row>
  </Container>
```

I have my closing  tags so not sure why I a getting the error?

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284169/parse-error-adjacent-jsx-elements-must-be-wrapped-in-an-enclosing-tag)

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The return of your map also needs to be wrapped in a containing tag, you can use React fragment tags <>  https://reactjs.org/docs/fragments.html#short-syntax

```
<Container>
    <Row>
      {this.state.products.map(product => (
         <>
           <Col md={8}>
              <div className="title">{product.name}</div>
              <div className="desc">{product.description}</div>
           </Col>
          <Col md={4}>
            <div className="price">{product.price}</div>
          </Col>
      </>
      ))}
    </Row>
  </Container>
```

Answer (score 1):

Try this:

The problem is, your `map` on the products `Array` is returning two components of type `Col`, and React only accepts one returned element.

[Explained here](https://medium.com/@schlunzk/adjacent-jsx-elements-must-be-wrapped-in-an-enclosing-tag-e9da57bdb5d4).

Also, `<React.Fragment></React.Fragmint>` Component Wrapper can also be written with this syntax: `<></>`

```
  <Container>
    <Row>
      {this.state.products.map(product => (
        <React.Fragment>
          <Col md={8}>
            <div className="title">{product.name}</div>
            <div className="desc">{product.description}</div>
          </Col>
          <Col md={4}>
            <div className="price">{product.price}</div>
          </Col>
        </React.Fragment>
      ))}
    </Row>
  </Container>
```