# .map would not return <td> tag twice ReactJS

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I am trying to return a row using map function twice. One information is fetched from one map and the second from the other. Apparently, in the second map function I am only able to return only one  tag and the second one gives me the error.

I have tried the following code which gives an error "Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...?"

```
tpList.map((val) => {
                        return (
                            <tr>
                                <th scope="row">{val}</th>
                                {name.map((val) => {
                                    return (
                                        <td>{val}</td>
                                        <td>{intake}</td>
                                    )
                                })
                                }
                            </tr>
                        )
                    })
```

[What I am trying to achieve here.](https://i.stack.imgur.com/nbZfb.png)

[What happens if I wrap the two  around a fragmnent](https://i.stack.imgur.com/wme96.png)

Comment: It's just what the error says, you can only return one element from the map, i.e. wrap the 2 `<td>`s

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Parse Error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284169/parse-error-adjacent-jsx-elements-must-be-wrapped-in-an-enclosing-tag)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Assuming that the indexes of the `name` array and the `tpList` array correspond to each other, you could do this:

```
tpList.map((val, i) => {
  return (
    <tr>
      <th scope="row">{val}</th>
      <td>{name[i]}</td>
      <td>{intake}</td>
    </tr>
  );
});
```

Answer (score 0):

The simplest solution is:

```
return (
           <div>
             <td>{val}</td>
             <td>{intake}</td>
           </div> 
       );
```

or:

```
return (
           <>
             <td>{val}</td>
             <td>{intake}</td>
           </> 
       );
```