# Could not add multiple counters in react

Tags: javascript, reactjs

I want to make a counter app with increment, decrement and add counter button. But add counter function is not working. It's showing this error:

> Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...?

i have already tried enclosing it in tags,still its not working.

```
import React,{Component} from 'react';
import './App.css';


export class App extends Component {
  state={
    count:0,
  }

  increment=()=>{
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }

  decrement=()=>{
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 });
  }

  addCounter=()=>{

        <span><button onClick={this.increment}>+</button></span>

         <span>{this.state.count}</span>
         <span><button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button></span>


  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">


      <button onClick={this.addCounter}>Add Counter</button>
      </div>



    )
  }
}




export default App;
```

add counter function should add another counter just below the previous counter.

Comment: You have to have a single root for any JSX element. The easiest way to get there is to wrap your elements with <React.Fragment></React.Fragment> (newer versions of react will also support <> </> as syntactic sugar). In your cast, you need to do so for the elements returned in addCounter.

Note that this was answered before, e.g.: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284169/parse-error-adjacent-jsx-elements-must-be-wrapped-in-an-enclosing-tag

Comment: Your "counter" needs to be a react component with its own state, what you have there will have each "counter" you add use the same component state from `App`.

Answer (score 2):

Basically extract a `Counter` component.

Then have your `App` maintain a list of `Counter` components.

```
// Counter Component
export class Counter extends React.Component {
  state = {
    count:0,
  }

  increment=()=>{
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count + 1 });
  }

  decrement=()=>{
    this.setState({ count: this.state.count - 1 });
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <span><button onClick={this.increment}>+</button></span>
        <span>{this.state.count}</span>
        <span><button onClick={this.decrement}>-</button></span>
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

```
// App Component
export class App extends React.Component {
  state = {
    counters: [], // additional state for Counter components
  }

  addCounter = () => {
    this.setState({
      counters: [
        ...this.state.counters,
        Counter
      ]
    })
  }

  render() {
    return (
      <div className="App">
        <button onClick={this.addCounter}>Add Counter</button>
        { this.state.counters.map((Counter, index) => (
           <Counter key={index} />)
        )}
      </div>
    )
  }
}
```

[Demo](https://codesandbox.io/embed/react-codesandbox-8bqo3)

Answer (score 0):

You are just adding more spans and button but refering to the same counter.

```
state={
  i : 0,
  count:0,
}
var newCount="counter"+this.state.i;
this.setState({
 i : this.state.i+1,
})
this.setState({
  count: {
     ...this.state.count,
     newCount: 0
  }
});
```

So with this you add a new counter with a progresive autoincrement number.

Answer (score 0):

You have to add another functional Component instead of adding JSX. [DEMO](https://codesandbox.io/s/busy-shadow-vmji5?fontsize=14)

```
import React from 'react';
const counter = (props) => {
   return (
      <div>
         <span><button onClick={() => props.increment(props.index)}>+</button></span>
             <span>{props.count}</span>
         <span><button onClick={() => props.decrement(props.index)}>-</button></span>
      </div>
   )
}    
export default counter;
```

And your main App component

```
import React, {Component} from 'react';
import Counter from './Counter';
import './App.css';


export class App extends Component {
  state={
     counters: []
  }

  valueChanger = (index, inc) => {
     this.setState((prevState) => {
        const counters = prevState.counters.slice();
        counters[index] += inc; 
        return {
            counters: counters
        }
     });
  }

  increment=(index)=>{
     this.valueChanger(index, 1);
  }

  decrement=(index)=>{
     this.valueChanger(index, -1);
  }

  addCounter=()=>{
     this.setState((prevState) => { 
        return { counters: [...prevState.counters, 0] }
     });
  }

  render() {
    let counterElems = this.state.counters.map((c, index) => {
       return <Counter key={index} index={index} increment={this.increment} decrement={this.decrement} count={c} />
    });

    return (
      <div className="App">
          {counterElems}
          <button onClick={this.addCounter}>Add Counter</button>
      </div>
    )
  }
}

export default App;
```

Answer (score 0):

Your "counter" needs to be a react component with its own state, what you have there will have each "counter" you add use the same component state from `App`. You also do not save the returned JSX to then render anywhere.

```
const Counter = () => {
  const [count, setCount] = useState(0);

  return (
    <div> // <-- React components can return only a single node*
      <span>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count + 1)}>+</button>
      </span>
      <span>{count}</span>
      <span>
        <button onClick={() => setCount(count - 1)}>-</button>
      </span>
    </div>
  );
};

class App extends Component {
  state = {
    counters: []
  };

  addCounter = () => {
    this.setState(prevState => ({
      counters: [...prevState.counters, <Counter />]
    }));
  };

  render() {
    return (
      <div>
        <button onClick={this.addCounter}>Add Counter</button>
        {this.state.counters}
      </div>
    );
  }
}
```

[image: Edit frosty-monad-bc71e]

* React [render lifecycle function](https://reactjs.org/docs/react-component.html#render) can render arrays.

Answer (score 0):

I think it is what you want to do.

```js
const { useState } = React;
function App(){
  const [counter, setCounter] = useState([]);
  
  function addCounter(){
    setCounter(counter.concat({id: counter.length, count: 0}));
  }
  function increase(id){
    setCounter(counter.map(el=>{
      if(el.id === id){
        el.count++;
      }
      return el;
    }));
  }
  function decrease(id){
    setCounter(counter.map(el=>{
      if(el.id === id){
        el.count--;
      }
      return el;
    }));
  }
  return (
    <div className="App">
      <button onClick={addCounter}>Add Counter</button>
      {
        counter.map(el=>{
          return(
            <div key={el.id}>
              <span>Counter #{el.id}</span>
              <div>
                <button onClick={()=>{increase(el.id)}}>+</button>
                <span>{el.count}</span>
                <button onClick={()=>{decrease(el.id)}}>-</button>
              </div>
            </div>
          )
        })
      }
    </div>
  )
}

ReactDOM.render(
  <App />, document.getElementById('root')
)
```

```html
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react@16/umd/react.development.js"></script>
<script crossorigin src="https://unpkg.com/react-dom@16/umd/react-dom.development.js"></script>
<div id="root"></div>
```