# Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag while adding bootstrap to my react code

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-native, navbar

```
Line 15:1:  Parsing error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag. Did you want a JSX fragment <>...</>?

  13 |   //crossorigin></script>
  14 | 
> 15 | <script>var Alert = ReactBootstrap.Alert;</script>
     | ^
```

Comment: Somewhere in a component's render you have adjacent jsx elements (like the error is telling you). So you need to wrap those in a parent element, like a View or Fragment.

Comment: Does this solve your issue: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284169/parse-error-adjacent-jsx-elements-must-be-wrapped-in-an-enclosing-tag

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Somewhere in your code you're doing:

```js
const Example = () => (
  <div />
  <div />
)
```

You cannot do that. React can only returns one parent element. So you have to wrap it with another `div`:

```js
const Example = () => (
  <div>
    <div />
    <div />
  </div>
)
```

However, this will bloat your markup with another `div` which is just to satisfy React. So you can use `React.Fragment` so that your markup doesn't have an unnecessary `div` like:

```js
const Example = () => (
  <React.Fragment>
    <div />
    <div />
  </React.Fragment>
)
```

Or in short, you can write it as:

```js
const Example = () => (
  <>
    <div />
    <div />
  </>
)
```

Comment: This answer is a slightly edited version of the top answer here https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284169/parse-error-adjacent-jsx-elements-must-be-wrapped-in-an-enclosing-tag. Maybe it's just better to close the question.

Comment: @BasvanderLinden true that. I didn't even bother looking.