# Next.js - using another <div></div> throws error, why?

Tags: javascript, html, next.js

Bear with me, I am just starting to explore Next.js ... I couldnt find any info on this error I got from using the html tag  two times. It works with just one  container, but as soon as I add another one, I get this:

`Error: error: Unexpected token "div". Expected jsx identifier`

Comment: Can you provid the code please ?

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Parse Error: Adjacent JSX elements must be wrapped in an enclosing tag](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/31284169/parse-error-adjacent-jsx-elements-must-be-wrapped-in-an-enclosing-tag)

Comment: @Tom it's exactly what Benjamin Carlson expected ;)

Comment: One of the quicker/more obvious causes is where you some kind of syntax error in the markup you are returning

Answer (score 8, accepted):

This is because you are trying to pass 2 children but Next.js only expects one. I believe you are doing something like this:

```js
return (
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>another div</div>
)
```

Instead you need to wrap both of these with another tag:

```js
return (
<>
    <div>div 1</div>
    <div>another div</div>
</>
)
```