# React.js “Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot”

Tags: reactjs

I know the mistake is from the nested stuff and  nested `_.map` function but I can't figure out how to do this.

Below a part of the render function:

What I want to do is:

1. Check is `this.props.currencylist` exists
2. Then display a `<select>` dropdown
3. with the `<options>` coming from the `this.props.currencylist`

```
{ 
  this.props.currencylist ?
  <select  id="fiatselector" onChange={this.onSelectCurrency} value {this.props.selectedcurrency}>
  { 
     _.map(this.props.currencylist, function(currency) { 
       return <option value={currency}> {currency} </option>  
     })
  }
  </select>
  : 
  ""
}
```

thanks a lot!

Btw, at the first render it works perfectly, it bugs when the  have to be updated, rerendering with a new currencylist trigger the error

Comment: Do you have a basic js fiddle that can be tested? Here's a link to a similar question: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026399/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-findcomponentroot-110-unable-to

Comment: Is this the component just rendering a dropdown list only? Meaning the root of the this component would be a `select` tag?

Comment: the dropdown list is a child of basic divs       <div className="panel panel-default"> then  <div className="panel-body">


I'm wondering if this way to render (nested option with _.map) is the right way to do

Comment: I've isolated the drop down, now it has only on parent, a basic div and it still triggers the same error =/

Comment: Can you post some more code? Hard to tell what the issue is? I've run into this issue once before with rendering `tables`. Google chrome adds `tbody` even if not specified. This cause the invariant error for me. I fixed it by adding the tbody in my markup. Yours seems different, but I would need more code to see.

Comment: More code won't help actually this render this simple element. I think I have isolated the problem , this.props.currencylist varies so when react may not find or find more new options than expected, something like that.
What do you think ? And how to fix that ?

Answer (score 16, accepted):

The actual problem here is the space around the value.

```
<option> {x} </option>
```

It should be:

```
<option>{x}</option>
```

The former ends up rendering:

```
<option><span> </span>{x}<span> </span></option>
```

The browser removes the span wrappers, but React still expects them to be there.

Comment: Good to know but I actually solved my problem removing the id of the <select>

Comment: I'd still remove the spaces.  In my case there is no `id`, but the spacing helped

Answer (score 1):

I was able to reproduce your error. Apparently you need to add the `key` attribute to your option tags. I wish I could provide a better explanation, but I don't know quite enough about ReactJs to explain.

Here is the relevant change based on your snippet (only change here is adding the `key` attribute. I just used the currency as the key here):

```
_.map(this.props.currencylist, function(currency) {
     return <option key={currency} value={currency}> {currency} </option>
})
```

Here is a simple example I used for testing (Slightly modified rendering but same idea):

```
var CurrentSelector = React.createClass({
    render: function() {
        var options = this.props.currencylist.map(function(currency) {
            return <option key={currency} value={currency}> {currency} </option>
        });
        if (this.props.currencylist) {
            return <div><select id="fiatselector">{options}</select></div>
        } else {
            return <div></div>
        }
    }
});

var App = React.createClass({
    getInitialState: function() {
        return {
            currencylist: [1,2,3],
            selectedcurrency: 1,
        }
    },
    render: function() {
        return (
            <div>
                <CurrentSelector
                    currencylist={this.state.currencylist}
                    selectedcurrency={this.state.selectedcurrency} />
                <button onClick={this.handleClick}>test</button>
            </div>
        );
    },
    handleClick: function() {
        this.setState({
            currencylist: [2, 3, 4, 5],
            selectedcurrency: 2,
        })
    }
});
```

Comment: The key forces a react component to update whenever the key changes. Whenever the key value changes, react will re-render the entire component. The key value is a really good strategy for when dynamic components are throwing invariant violations. It works a lot of the time.