# Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation Error

Tags: reactjs

I am trying to display a simple table of data using React. I get the error

"Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: processUpdates(): Unable to find child 1 of element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a  when using tables, nesting tags like ,

, or , or using non-SVG elements in an  parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID `.0.1.0`."

Not sure why this is happening

Here is the code

```
 render: function() {

      self = this;


      // render each campaign row
      var campaigns = this.state.campaigns.map(function(p){
        return <CampaignItem key={p.id} campaignName={p.campaign_name} />
      });

      console.log(campaigns)


      // if nothing is loaded
      if(!campaigns.length){
          campaigns = <p>Loading campaigns..</p>;
      }
      return (
        <div>
          <h2>Campaigns</h2>
          <div className="table-responsive">
            <table className="table table-bordered table-striped">
              <thead>
                <th>
                  <tr>
                    <th>
                    Campaign Name
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </th>
              </thead>

              <tbody>
                {campaigns}
              </tbody>

            </table>
          </div>
        </div>

      );
  }
});


var CampaignItem = React.createClass({


  render: function() {
    return (
      <tr>
        <td>{this.props.campaignName}
        </td>

      </tr>
    );
  }

});
```

Comment: Have you tried wrapping the empty state (`!campaigns.length`) value in a `tr` and `td`? A `tbody` shouldn't contain a `p` directly.

Comment: When there are no campaigns you are rendering a `p` tag inside of `tbody` and that might be causing this error: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026399/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-findcomponentroot-110-unable-to  - also you have some `th` tags outside of the `tr` `<th>
                  <tr>
                    <th>
                    Campaign Name
                    </th>
                  </tr>
                </th>`

Comment: I removed both the extra th tags and changed the `p` to a `<tr><th>` and all seems to be good

Answer (score 1):

I removed both the extra th tags and changed the p to a  and all seems to be good