# React modal - invariant violation

Tags: javascript, twitter-bootstrap, reactjs

I have a **React** application which uses a **Bootstrap** modal:

```
<div id="newListModal" className="modal fade" role="dialog">
    <div className="modal-dialog">

        <div className="modal-content">
            <div className="modal-header">
                <button type="button" className="close" data-dismiss="modal">&times;</button>
                <h4 className="modal-title">Create new list</h4>
            </div>

            <div className="modal-body">
                <div>
                    <p>Select category</p>
                    <select class="form-control" onChange={this.handleSelect}>
                        {categoryDesc}
                    </select>
                    {this.state.categorySelected == true
                        ?
                        <div>
                            <p>Select classification</p>
                            <select class="form-control">
                                {this.state.classificationDesc}
                            </select>
                        </div>
                        :
                        <div></div>}
                </div>
            </div>

            <div className="modal-footer">
                <button type="button" className="btn btn-default" data-dismiss="modal" onClick={this.closeModal}>Close</button>
            </div>
        </div>

    </div>
</div>
```

I have two dropdowns. First time I select them, everything is fine.
However, if I try to select the first again I get:

```
Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., .0.2.1.0.0.1.0.2.1.0.0): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated (e.g., by the browser), usually due to forgetting a <tbody> when using tables, nesting tags like <form>, <p>, or <a>, or using non-SVG elements in an <svg> parent. Try inspecting the child nodes of the element with React ID ``
```

[Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., ...$110): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026399/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-findcomponentroot-110-unable-to) is a similar question but I don't use any table

Any ideas about what is causing this error?

Comment: What is the value of {categoryDesc} and {this.state.classificationDesc}?

Comment: `var categoryDesc = this.props.categories.map(function (elem, index) {
            return <option value={index}><a href="#">{elem.description}</a></option>
        });` `this.state.classificationDesc` is similar

Answer (score 0):

You need to pass an unique `key` prop for all your dynamic children

```
   <p>Select category</p>
   <select class="form-control" onChange={this.handleSelect}>
    {this.props.categories.map(function (elem, index) { 
       return (
        <option value={index} key={"category" + index}>
          <a href="#">{elem.description}</a>
        </option>
       );
    })}
   </select>
```

> The situation gets more complicated when the children are shuffled around (as in search results) or if new components are added onto the front of the list (as in streams). In these cases where the identity and state of each child must be maintained across render passes, you can uniquely identify each child by assigning it a key

For more info see https://facebook.github.io/react/docs/multiple-components.html#dynamic-children