# Dispatching an action from a service in Redux

Tags: reactjs, redux

I have a logging function which logs errors. When an Ajax Request fails with a non `JSON` data type, the `log` method should log it, however, we are getting the mutated error as the attached screenshot shows. I am trying to call this `log` action within a `service`.

**Code**

```
...
import {log} from '../actions/LoggingActions';
...
export default function request(url, opts, dispatch, type = 'application/x-www-form-urlencoded') {
  ...

  return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
    $.ajax(args).then((data) => {
      dispatch(httpEndRequest([url, opts, dispatch]));
      resolve(data);
    }).fail((jqXHR, textStatus, errorThrown) => {
      const error = (jqXHR && jqXHR.responseJSON) ?
                      jqXHR.responseJSON.message :
                      'Error Making Request';
      dispatch(httpFailRequest([url, opts, dispatch], error));
      try {
        reject(JSON.parse(jqXHR.responseText));
      } catch (e) {
        console.log(jqXHR.responseText, jqXHR, error);
        reject(error);
        dispatch(log('Received data is not in JSON format', {requestUrl: url}, {result: e, response: jqXHR, status: textStatus, error: errorThrown}, 'error'));
      }
    });
  });
}
```

[image]

Comment: Using jQuery with React? Deal with effects. Check where you removed DOM element without sync with React.

Comment: Doesn't seem like a good idea to have jquery doing that. Check this http://stackoverflow.com/questions/38836553/how-to-use-jquery-ui-with-react-js/40350880#40350880

Comment: Thanks guys, I modified the code to use `axios` and the issue still persists.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Instead of using jQuery with React, Use [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios) or [fetch](https://github.com/github/fetch) (Promise based HTTP clients). I personally prefer axios.

To use [axios](https://github.com/mzabriskie/axios), do
`npm install axios --save`. Then

```
import axios from 'axios';


return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
  axios.get(url, {
    params: params
  })
    .then((response) => {
      resolve(response.data);
    })
    .catch((error) => {
      // error.response.status
      dispatch(log(error));
      reject(error);
    });
});
```

Comment: + for axios, simple

Comment: Thanks for the converted sample code, I have converted my code to use `axios`, but the issue still persists..

Comment: Then I think issue is with something else here. A similar issue is here http://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026399/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-findcomponentroot-110-unable-to. 
See if you can figure out what the issue is or share some more code to understand the problem better.