# Set reset button in dropdown list

Tags: reactjs, react-native, button, drop-down-menu

I'm new to react native. I have made dropdown list but i want one reset button whenever i click it reset the default label. Here is my code of simple dropown list.I want one reset button.

```
<Picker
  style={{width:'80%'}}
  selectedValue={this.state.PickerValue}
  onValueChange={(itemValue,itemIndex) => 
  this.setState({PickerValue:itemValue})}>
    <Picker.Item label="Select a option" value=""/>
    <Picker.Item label="Html" value="html" />
    <Picker.Item label="Javascript" value="javascript"/>
</Picker>
```

Answer (score 2, accepted):

While I have no experience with Picker, setting the value of your dropdown using a button can be done by doing this:

```
setDropdownValue = () => {
    document.getElementById("languagePicker").selectedIndex = "0";
};

<button onClick={this.setDropdownValue}>Reset selected picker value</button>
```

Dont forget to replace:

```
<Picker
to
<Picker id="languagePicker"
```

Comment: which i haven't added yet

Comment: I updated my first response, did you mean a solution like that?

Comment: no,it's not working i'm getting error of invariant violation.

Comment: i just want one reset button, when i click that button it show nothing selected. i want that when i click that button 2 options which i have added not show

Comment: For the invariant violation error I would like to link you to this page: [Error invariant violation](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026399/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-findcomponentroot-110-unable-to)

Comment: thanks,but i just want reset list items onclick button

Comment: Is this what you meant?

Comment: thanks, for your effort but i want one button suppose reset .i have three options in dropdown list "Select a option","Html","java".onclick of button i want that it show first option i.e "Slecet a option"

Comment: Hi @shabnamsingh is everything working correctly? If not, let me know

Comment: yes everthing working fine. I just take three state and on reset button i selct the first state. and code is working fine

Comment: can you plzz do one more help

Comment: Hey @shabnamsingh what is the matter? Do you have another question?

Comment: yes i'm getting problem in retrieving data from firebase.

Comment: Here is the link of my question https://stackoverflow.com/questions/53424115/fetch-data-from-firebase

Comment: @shabnamsingh unfortunately, I have no experience with React Native or with Firebase so I can help you here.