# React JS - Invariant violation error while using HOC

Tags: reactjs, jsx

While learning higher order component in react, I was trying to use it in my code. While doing so, I am getting "Invariant Violation Error"

```
//Higher Order Component
const withStyles = (OriginalComponent) => {
  class NewComponent extends React.Component{
    render(){
      return <OriginalComponent />  
    }
  }
  return NewComponent;
}

class FancyButton extends React.Component {
  render() {
    return <button>Fancy button</button>;
  }
}


const App = props => {
//I am calling the HOC to get my updated component
  let Enhanced = withStyles(<FancyButton />);

  return (
      <Enhanced />
  );
};

ReactDOM.render(<App />, document.getElementById("root"));
```

Here I am calling the HOC(withStyles) and storing the returned component in a variable "Enhanced". In the App component, Can I directly call Enhanced component like  ?

I expect the output should be button element, but I am getting "Invariant Violation" error

Comment: Possible duplicate of [Uncaught Error: Invariant Violation: findComponentRoot(..., ...$110): Unable to find element. This probably means the DOM was unexpectedly mutated](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/25026399/uncaught-error-invariant-violation-findcomponentroot-110-unable-to)

Answer (score 0):

You are passing a rendered result of FancyButton, whereas you should've passed the actual component function
See below:

```
...
const App = props => {
//I am calling the HOC to get my updated component
  let Enhanced = withStyles(FancyButton);

  return (
      <Enhanced />
  );
};
...
```

Comment: If I have to modify the above code to call the Enhanced component then how to do that?